# How can I destructure an array within my object in React ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently developing a React app where an Application will be selected, and the waterTypes for this application should then be returned.

I therefore need to destructure the waterTypes array within my filtered ApplicationData object. The array will have either 1, 2, or 3 values present.

Currently my waterTypes variable is returning undefined to the console. How can I get this to return the waterTypes from the selected Application?

ChoicesProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ChoicesContext = createContext(null);

export const ChoicesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    category: null,
  });

  return (
    <ChoicesContext.Provider value={{ choices, setChoices }}>
      {children}
    </ChoicesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

ApplicationData.js

```
const ApplicationData = [
  {
    name: 'App1',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1']
  },
  {
    name: 'App2',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2']
  },
  {
    name: 'App3',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
  },
];

export default ApplicationData
```

Product.js

```
const Product = () => {
  const { choices, setChoices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);

  const CurrentApplication = ApplicationData.filter(x => x.name === choices.category);

  const { waterTypes } = CurrentApplication;
  console.log(waterTypes);

  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
};

export default Product
```

Comment: Array.filter always returns another array - even if only one element is found.

Comment: `CurrentApplication` is going to be an array not a single object. If you want to destructure the first element in the array, `var {waterTypes} = CurrentApplication[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead of `filter`, to destructure an object not an array of one item

```js
const ApplicationData = [
  {
    name: 'App1',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1']
  },
  {
    name: 'App2',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2']
  },
  {
    name: 'App3',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
  },
];

 const CurrentApplication = ApplicationData.find(x => x.name === 'App3');

  const { waterTypes } = CurrentApplication;
  
  console.log(waterTypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter always returns an array

```
const Product = () => {
const { choices, setChoices } = useContext(ChoicesContext);

const CurrentApplication = ApplicationData.filter(x => x.name === choices.category);

const { waterTypes } = CurrentApplication[0];
console.log(waterTypes);

 return (
  <>
  </>
```

);
   } ;

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter` will always return an array, if you want to use filter you have loop over the `filteredArray` to get the value

```js
const applicationData = [
  {
    name: 'App1',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1']
  },
  {
    name: 'App2',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2']
  },
  {
    name: 'App3',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
  },
];

const filteredArray = applicationData.filter(data => data.name === 'App3');

for (let item of filteredArray) {
  const { waterTypes } = item;
  
  console.log(waterTypes);
  
}
```

Also you can use `Array.prototype.find` is you only want to find one item in the array based of a condition.

For example,

```js
const applicationData = [
  {
    name: 'App1',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1']
  },
  {
    name: 'App2',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2']
  },
  {
    name: 'App3',
    waterTypes: ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
  },
];

const { waterTypes } = applicationData.find(data => data.name === 'App3');

console.log(waterTypes)
```